# Judaism on gaining confidence

Tags: psych-mentalhealth

What would Jewish sources say about confidence (not self confidence, more like social interaction confidence) and how one could gain it if they’re lacking in it

Comment: Surely self-confidence allows for a greater ability to interact with others? I don't quite see the difference?